# Can't POST data jquery to phpmailer

Tags: javascript, php, phpmailer

Html form:

```
<form id="contacts-form">
  <input name="email" type="text">
  <textarea name="contacts-form-textarea"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var $form = $("#contacts-form");
$form.on("submit", submitHandler);

function submitHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/sendmail2.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $form.serialize()
  }).done(response => {
    if (JSON.parse(response).success) {
      console.log('success');
      $form.trigger('reset');
    } else {
      console.log('fail');
    }
  });
}
```

sendmail2.php (basically the [official phpmailer example for gmail](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) with minor modifications):

```
<?php
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

// require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "mypass";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');

//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('anotherone@gmail.com', 'My Name');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
// $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contentss.html'), __DIR__);
$mail->msgHTML('<h1>' . $_POST["email"] . '</h1>');

//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

//Attach an image file
// $mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    // echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    $results = array('success' => false);
    echo json_encode($results);
} else {
    // echo "Message sent!";
    $results = array('success' => true);
    echo json_encode($results);
    //Section 2: IMAP
    //Uncomment these to save your message in the 'Sent Mail' folder.
    #if (save_mail($mail)) {
    #    echo "Message saved!";
    #}
}

//Section 2: IMAP
//IMAP commands requires the PHP IMAP Extension, found at: https://php.net/manual/en/imap.setup.php
//Function to call which uses the PHP imap_*() functions to save messages: https://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php
//You can use imap_getmailboxes($imapStream, '/imap/ssl') to get a list of available folders or labels, this can
//be useful if you are trying to get this working on a non-Gmail IMAP server.
function save_mail($mail)
{
    //You can change 'Sent Mail' to any other folder or tag
    $path = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}[Gmail]/Sent Mail";

    //Tell your server to open an IMAP connection using the same username and password as you used for SMTP
    $imapStream = imap_open($path, $mail->Username, $mail->Password);

    $result = imap_append($imapStream, $path, $mail->getSentMIMEMessage());
    imap_close($imapStream);

    return $result;
}
```

Mail sending works as expected, I receive the message on my email. But for some reason the `data` is not getting sent to the `sendmail2.php`.

When I console.log the data in the JS file it works fine, but `$_POST["email"]` on the backend returns `null`. I tried

```
var data = {
  email: $("#contacts-form input").val()
};
```

and in my JS, didn't work either.

Comment: Why don't you send mail without js ?

Comment: I checked, your code is working fine, there is no issue in it You need to check your server side code

Comment: First you need to give us the file system structure, even if we can determine it ourself. E.g. the location of the pages and of the phpmailer folder. Case sensitive, of course.

Comment: Also: (1) `done` method's correct definition is `jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});`. (2) You must implement an error callback with `jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {})`. (3) You are expecting a json-encoded response. So set the property `dataType: 'json',` in ajax.

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` check what this return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was caused by these .htaccess rules used to hide the `.php` extension in the urls:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Other than that, the code from the initial post works as expected.

**ADDED:**

The rules above can be replaced by the following (with no affect on mail sending):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

In POST, the object is enclosed in the data property. So you might have to access the data in your PHP file through;

```
$_POST['data'];
```

Since it's an object, you have to decode

```
$data = json_decode( $_POST['data'], true);
```

Then access it using;

```
$data['email'];
```

Be sure to have your format like this data property in your ajax like this;

```
data: { 'email':'test@test.com' }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `$.ajax({})` to send data to the server, the `data` property is supposed to be an `object`, not a `string`.

The `$form.serialize()` return a string, not an `object`.

### Example:

Using `$.ajax()` to save some data to the server and notify the user once it's complete.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }    // it needs an object, not a string
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

More information is available here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for your input. If I send something like `data: { email:'test@test.com' }` it doesn't work either

Comment: have you tried to hard cording the `data: { test: 'abc' }`, this way help us to know where the error occurs, client-side or server-side